# PHP - add SPACE on a POST Variable

Tags: php, forms, post

when using php, i send a value to email via POST method, i want it to add a space, after the 6th character (number in this case) when showing up on the email.
So via php, i send it on this way:

```
ID Number : ".$_POST['idnumber']."
```

and when i get it on the email, currently is like this:

```
ID Number : 965128523171363920
```

So what i'm trying to do is to add a space after the sixth number when it comes to my email, that would look like this:

```
ID Number : 965128 523171363920
```

Is this possible on PHP, i'm sorry i'm a newbie on this..
**Thank You in Advance**

Comment: `preg_replace('~^(\d{6})~', '\\1 ', $_POST['idnumber'])`

Comment: Don't forget to validate $_POST (and $_GET and $_COOKIE) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$first_six = substr($_POST['idnumber'], 0, 6);
$the_rest = substr($_POST['idnumber'], 6);
//Merge the two strings
$final = $first_six.' '.$the_rest;
```

More info [here](http://www.php.net/substr)

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else for replying, the Lance's code was very easy and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr) to get the parts of the strings you want.

```
echo sprintf("%s %s", substr($_POST['idnumber'],0, 6), substr($_POST['idnumber'], 6));
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/Fp6uO)